# How to insert brackets only around an operand coming immediately after an squareroot in a mathematical expression?

Tags: android, regex, replace

If user types : √3 + 2

I want to change it to : sqrt(3) + 2

I am working in android studio and hence, the language is Java. This is required by the MXParser library that I am using. I understand that I can use replaceAll function to replace '√' with 'sqrt(' but putting ')' after the operand and before the following operator is what I want to know. I understand I have to use regex for this but don't know how to use it for getting this desired result.

Your help is appreciated :)

Also, can you please also point out to a good resource from where I can read and learn how to use REGEX for such similar requirements in future (if any arise)?

Comment: "I understand that I can use replaceAll function to replace '√' with 'sqrt('..."  Please show what you have done so far.

Comment: I tried to use regex by using: expression = expression.replaceAll("\\√+\\d", "($1)");
But this didn't work. I tried a few permutation by changing brackets and characters positions in the regex but couldn't get it.

Comment: Please make an MCVE http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Learning regex could be done by searching for a tutorial in the web. https://www.ixquick.de/do/search?q=regex+tutorial Or any search engine of your preference. I do not think that you need a specially selected one. Just look for one where the first few pages are clear and understandable to you. Otherwise learning regex is playing with regex. How about studying a few stackoverflow questions with regex tag an their answers.

Comment: @Yunnosch Thank you for the suggestion. Perhaps reading a few StackOverflow questions on regex is a good starting point. I shall do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to figure this out with Regex.

With the following line of code, one can easily replace '√' with 'sqrt()' with the number being within the brackets:

```
expression = expression.replaceAll("√(\\d+)", "sqrt($1)");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
        String str = "√2 + 3";
        str = str + " ";
        String firstDelim = "√";
        int p1 = str.indexOf(firstDelim);
        Log.i("p1 ", "p1 " + p1);

        if (p1 >= 0) {

            int k = p1 + firstDelim.length();

            for (int i = p1 + 1; i < str.length(); i++) {
                String a = str.substring(i, i + 1);
                if (!isInt(a)) {
                k = i;
                break;
                }
            }

        String temp = str;
        String res = temp.substring(p1 + firstDelim.length(), k);
        str = str.replace(res, res + ")");
        str = str.replace("√", "sqrt(");
        System.out.println(str);
        }
```

and isInt is just a function as:

```
static boolean isInt(String s)
    {
     try
      { int i = Integer.parseInt(s); return true; }

     catch(NumberFormatException er)
      { return false; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Frankly speaking you can play with the tokens using [mXparser](http://mathparser.org/) as well.

```
import org.mariuszgromada.math.mxparser.*;
...
...
Expression e = new Expression("√3 + 2");
mXparser.consolePrintTokens(e.getCopyOfInitialTokens());
```

Result:

```
[mXparser-v.4.0.0]  --------------------
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] | Expression tokens: |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0]  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |    TokenIdx |       Token |        KeyW |     TokenId | TokenTypeId |  TokenLevel |  TokenValue |   LooksLike |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0]  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |           0 |          √3 |             |          -1 |          -1 |           0 |         NaN |       error |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |           1 |           + |           + |           1 |           1 |           0 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |           2 |           2 |       _num_ |           1 |           0 |           0 |         2.0 |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0]  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So let's play with the tokens

```
String exprStr = "√3 + 2";
Expression e = new Expression(exprStr);
ArrayList<Token> tokens = e.getCopyOfInitialTokens();
String newExprStr = "";
for (Token t : tokens) {
    String toAdd = t.tokenStr;
    if (t.tokenStr.charAt(0) == '√')
            toAdd = "sqrt(" + t.tokenStr.substring(1) + ")";
    newExprStr = newExprStr + toAdd;
}
mXparser.consolePrintln(newExprStr);
```

Result:

```
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] sqrt(3)+2
```

Please follow [mXparser tutorial](http://mathparser.org/mxparser-tutorial/), [mXparser math collection](http://mathparser.org/mxparser-math-collection/) and [mXparser API](http://mathparser.org/api/) definition.

Best regards :-)